# PHP Complaing on redeclare in same fil, but only on declare. Bug?

Tags: php, macos, apache, function-declaration

I am getting following error message:

```
   [Wed Sep 21 21:19:46 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare db_get_groups() 
(previously declared in /Library/WebServer/Documents/SMICAdmin/databasescripts/db_get_groups.php:4) 
in /Library/WebServer/Documents/SMICAdmin/databasescripts/db_get_groups.php on line 24, 
referer: http://localhost/SMICAdmin/index.php
```

As you can see, the error message complains that the same function, db_get_groups(), twice in the same script. But it's not, the entire file is included here (db_get_groups.php):

```
<?php

    function db_get_groups($dbconnection){  //Line 4

        $query = "SELECT id FROM groups";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query);

        $rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $grouplist = Array();

        foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
            error_log(" Value -> ".$value['id']);
            $grouplist[] = $value['id'];

        }

    return $grouplist;
    } //Line 24
    ?>
```

When doing a search for "db_get_groups" in the entire project I can only find the only declaration below and the file is inluded in two other files for usage.

I did try to find if I done some import of the file more than once in some way, couldn't find any.

What's the problem and how do I fix it? Feels really wired this one...

Comment: Are you sure your file isn't included twice in index.php?

Comment: To touch on what @AlanMoore said, try `include_once(db_get_groups.php)`

Comment: what are the results of function_exists(db_get_groups);?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is that the only way you would ever see that error message is if the function is defined twice. There's two common ways this could happen. You should double check both of these:

1. Another file declares the function `db_get_groups`.
2. `db_get_groups.php` is included multiple times. Consider using `include_once` / `require_once` instead of just `include` / `require`.

Comment: I took the easy way and just defined all to include_once. Don't know what the problem was. There were a lot of redeclarations following this one. From none to many...strange.

Answer (score 1):

Use:
require_once("db_get_groups.php");

Or,
include_once("db_get_groups.php");

Instead of just require or include.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing that definition, and calling db_get_groups(), see if there are any hints in the error logs.

If that doesn't go anywhere, are you perhaps including the file more than one time? Are you including both those other files that include it somewhere?

Did you use require/include or require_once/include_once? Try *_once.

Are there any symbolic links to that file? If so, could you be including them as well?

Finally, it could help you if you added a log() or echo() outside the function (before it).